# Generate SSL certificate using Keytool

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, keytool

I have a question about SSL certificates.

I use Openssl to generate the certificate: I followed this [tutorial](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html). My goal is to generate:

- .crt
- .key
- .pem

Is possible to obtain the same files using keytool?

Answer (score 2):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format) outlines obtaining certificates from a Java keystore like you would generate with keytool in PEM and PKCS#12 format.  In short:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore srckeystore.jks -destkeystore dest.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12

$ openssl pkcs12 -in dest.p12 -out dest.pem
```

You will end up with your keys and certs in PEM format, as well as a PKCS#12 copy of the keystore.  Note that this still requires using openSSL to convert the PKCS#12 keystore to .PEM format.  If you export directly from JKS to PEM you will not get the private keys out of the store.

Comment: One question: If I generate my certificate using keytool (I obtain the .crt file). I need also .key file (as as I use openssl to obtain .crt and .key). Is possible to extract also .key file using keytool?

Comment: The .pem file you get from the above operation will give you a pem with both the certs and keys.   A .key file is typically just a plaintext file containing the key, which is the same as a pem file.  You can just extract the key info from the pem and put it into a .key file.